# service doesn't work while another one is running

Tags: java, android

I have two services that listen for connections on two different ports and both of them work fine when only one of them is running but when I run one service while other one is running, the second service doesn't work as I expected

httpService

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: ");
    try {
        mAsy = new asy();
        mAsy.execute();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

class asy extends AsyncTask{
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
       try {
           server = new ServerSocket(25452);
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = server.accept();
                new Thread(new httpHandler(socket)).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(MyApplication.TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        mAsy = new asy();
        mAsy.execute();
    }
}
```

I start this service in onCreate method of my main activity

serverService

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    try {
        mAsy = new asy();
        mAsy.execute();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

class asy extends AsyncTask{
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(25432);
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = server.accept();
                new Thread(new connectionHandler(socket)).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(MyApplication.TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        mAsy = new asy();
        mAsy.execute();
    }
}
```

I start this service when a button is pressed in main activity

when I debug my app doInBackground method of serverService doesn't get call
while httpService is running

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `second service doesn't work as I expected`, What do you expected?

Comment: @Yu normally  my `serverService` open port number 25432 and I can connect to it but when `httpService` is running it doesn't

Comment: It looks normal. You can post a simple project somewhere, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are running this on API level >= 11. Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for `AsyncTask`:

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single
>   background thread. Starting with `DONUT`, this was changed to a pool of
>   threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with
>   `HONEYCOMB`, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common
>   application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke
>   `executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[])` with
>   `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`.

What this means is that your `AsyncTask` in `serverService` will never get to execute as the thread in charge of executing AsyncTasks is already occupied by your `AsyncTask` in `httpService`.

While you *could* resolve this by allowing parallel execution of AsyncTasks as explained in the quote above, this is not the way you want to go about this. Your use of AsyncTasks contradicts 100% with their intended use (again quoting [the API documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)):

> `AsyncTask` is designed to be a helper class around `Thread` and `Handler`
>   and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks
>   should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the
>   most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time,
>   it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the
>   `java.util.concurrent` package such as `Executor`, `ThreadPoolExecutor` and
>   `FutureTask`.